# How can I configure Commitlint and Husky for Java projects?

Tags: java, spring-boot, devops

I'm using [Commitlint](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint) and [Husky](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-commit-hooks-to-git-with-husky-to-automate-code-tasks/#what-is-husky) for my Node.js projects. How can I use the same concept for Spring Boot projects as well? I am not getting enough leads.

This is for Java/Spring Boot projects with [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#What_is_the_POM.3F).

Comment: The title is not representative.

Answer (score -3):

combine spotless with commitlint for spring boot project

`Spotless` is a code formatter for Java (and other languages) that integrates with build tools like Gradle and Maven, whereas `commitlint` is a tool for linting commit messages in a Git repository. They serve different roles in a project, but they can certainly be used together to enforce both code style and commit message conventions in a Spring Boot project.

Here's a brief guide on how to configure each in a Spring Boot project:

### Spotless Setup with Gradle

1. Add the Spotless plugin to your build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '5.14.2'
}
```

2. Configure Spotless:

```
spotless {
  java {
    googleJavaFormat() // Use the Google Java Format
    target 'src/**/*.java' // Point to the Java source
  }
}
```

3. To format your code according to the defined rules, you can run:

```bash
./gradlew spotlessApply
```

4. To check if your code complies with the defined rules, you can run:

```bash
./gradlew spotlessCheck
```

### Commitlint Setup

Commitlint setup in a Spring Boot project can be accomplished as described in the previous messages. Here is a quick recap:

1. Install Node.js and npm.
2. Initialize a package.json in your project root:

```bash
npm init -y
```

3. Install commitlint and Husky:

```bash
npm install @commitlint/{config-conventional,cli} husky --save-dev
```

4. Configure commitlint:

```bash
echo "module.exports = {extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional']};" > commitlint.config.js
```

5. Configure Husky:

```bash
npx husky install
npx husky add .husky/commit-msg 'npx --no-install commitlint --edit "$1"'
```

### Combining Both

If you want to ensure that all checks pass before committing the code, you can add a pre-commit hook with Husky to run `./gradlew spotlessCheck`. Here's how you can do it:

1. First, install Husky and lint-staged:

```bash
npm install --save-dev husky lint-staged
```

2. Add a lint-staged configuration in your `package.json`:

```json
"lint-staged": {
  "*.java": [
    "./gradlew spotlessApply",
    "git add"
  ]
}
```

3. Install husky hooks:

```bash
npx husky install
```

4. Add pre-commit and commit-msg hooks:

```bash
npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npx lint-staged"
npx husky add .husky/commit-msg 'npx --no-install commitlint --edit "$1"'
```

This setup will run Spotless to format your Java files and add them to the commit. Then it will check the commit message using commitlint. If any of these steps fail, the commit will be aborted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, maycon araujo!

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: This answer has two completely different writing styles which suggests [some](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun) [kind of plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/), like [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiarism.

Comment: How is it getting correctly formatted as Markdown (using Stack Overflow tag formatting)? I can't imagine this to be a manual process. ChatGPT doesn't seem to have it. Or is it some setting that needs to be changed? Or part of ChatGPT Plus? Or something [almost, but not quite entirely, unlike ChatGPT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wAuDhoRmzg&t=8m4s)?

Comment: Or in other words, is there now a web site that ***specialises in Stack Overflow*** and makes it even easier to be a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) [plagiariser](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun)? I have seen other ChatGPT plagiarisers posting perfectly formatted answers (this is a marked change). Or is it only a coincidence?